# Re-asking an already closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

A [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34030/what-happened-to-voldemorts-final-corpse) was asked which was (deemed to be) not constructive. This was true of the way in which the question was asked.

But the question itself was (in my opinion) quite interesting, and I have wanted to know the answer for a while myself.

Unfortunately since I am not the OP, I cannot edit the question to make it more constructive and have the question re-opened.

Incidentally, I was asking my own question on the topic when I saw the (closed) question as related...

**Is it possible for me to ask a similar question (hopefully in a more constructive manner)?**

Quite interestingly, the said question has a wonderful [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/34035/21267), which the OP has un-accepted. What is the etiquette and/or rules of doing this?

Comment: `I cannot edit the question to make it more constructive and have the question re-opened.` - Err, yes you can, as long as it's not too drastic an edit.  For low-rep users, it goes into the review queue to be approved/denied.

Comment: Cool. good to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't just re-ask closed questions. Look into why it was closed, and get it reopened. Anyone (yes, you too) can do this by [making edits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/editing), and/or asking here on Meta why it was closed. If a discussion on Meta doesn't provide a path to reopening the question, or the question can't be salvaged by editing, then it's likely not appropriate for this site, in which case re-asking it is just going to result in the question being closed again.

Answer (score 2):

Given the quality of the answer, I'm not sure a new question is needed.  I'm not sure if you could've suggested an edit to improve it, but instead I just went ahead and edited it myself.  Maybe it'll get re-opened, but even if not, it's searchable and useful.

ADDED: Oops, I didn't see that you'd gone ahead and asked it again...  Yeah, the preferred thing to do for a salvageable question is to edit it or - if you can't or don't think you should edit it - to mention it on meta so someone else can try to save it.

Keep in mind that having a question closed as a dup is not a bad thing...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there's absolutely no reason you can't ask a [closed] question again, as long as the reason for it being closed in the first place wasn't due to it violating the site rules in some fashion.

If it does violate, it's pretty likely that the question will simply be closed again in fairly short order.